# Chosen select, how to get the multiple values into a $bind array

Tags: jquery, mysql, arrays, pdo, bind

im using aura sql with extendedPdo.
i have a form with a filter where you can select multiple options with chosen jquery as you can see i popoulate the options from the db. i dont know how to get multiple values from the form after i submit since im using $bind with $pdo.
i would like to add a "and pr.idproduttori = :produttore" for each option i selected. sorry for my bad english :D

template:

```
<select name="filter[produttore][]"  multiple class="chosen-select form-element" data-placeholder="Seleziona Produttore/i">
    <option value="">Tutti</option>
    <?php foreach ($produttori as $row): ?> 
                    <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>" <?= @$filter['produttore'] == $row['id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $row['prodname'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?> 
</select>
```

controller:

```
if(!empty($filter['produttore'])){
    foreach($filter['produttore'] as $row){
        $q_where .= ' and pr.idproduttori = :produttore';
        $bind['produttore'] = $row;
    }
}

if(!empty($filter['ean'])){
        $q_where .= ' and p.ean_code = :ean';
        $bind['ean'] = $filter['ean'];
}

// Query predefinita
$q = 'select p.idprodotti as id, pr.nome as produttore, p.modello, p.ean_code as ean, t.descrizione as tipo, count(o.idoggetti) as quanto
    from prodotti p join produttori pr on p.idproduttori = pr.idproduttori
    join tipologia t on p.idtipologia = t.idtipologia
    left join oggetti o on p.idprodotti = o.idprodotti';

$q_attribs = ' group by p.idprodotti order by '.$filter['orderby'].' '.$filter['verso'];

$data = $pdo->fetchAll($q.$q_where.$q_attribs, $bind);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works:

```
if(!empty($filter['produttore'])){
    $q_where .= ' and (';
    $i = 'a';
    foreach($filter['produttore'] as $row){
        $q_where .= 'pr.idproduttori = :'.$i.' or ';
        $bind[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    // d($bind[]);
    $q_where = substr($q_where,0,-4).')';
}
```

Is not really nice to see but it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I figure out that you mean smthg like that :

```
if(!empty($filter['produttore'])){
    $q_where .= ' and (';
    foreach($filter['produttore'] as $row){
        $q_where .= 'pr.idproduttori = :produttore or ';
        $bind['produttore'] = $row;
    }
    $q_where = substr($q_where,0,-4).')';
}
```

Comment: there is a problem at
$bind['produttore'] 
because if i do var_dump($bind['produttore']);
it says there is only the 2nd value i choose as filter into $bind['produttore'],
i need that $bind['produttore'] is an array

Comment: The fact that when you write `$bind['produttore']` overwrites a potentially existing value is normal. Don't you mean `$bind['produttore'][]`?

Comment: `$bind['produttore'][]`

doesnt work because you have to change the  `:produttore` in the string everytime